# Android-studio emulator build failed/Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new to programming.

I'm just trying to create android emulator but I had this error

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:616: error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:617: error: resource anim/abc_popup_exit (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_popup_exit) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:620: error: resource anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:621: error: resource anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:624: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_enter (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_tooltip_enter) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:625: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_exit (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:anim/abc_tooltip_exit) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:788: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:791: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_text_material (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_btn_colored_text_material) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:845: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:897: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:929: error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:932: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:933: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:934: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:935: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:936: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:937: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:938: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:939: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark) not found.
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDashboardsAppDjango\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:940: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light (aka com.example.mydashboardsapp_django:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light) not found.
```

I had tried to reinstalling emulator and android-studio itself

look through the setup document; https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

I read through some post on StackOverflow but, doesn't really relate to my problem.

I Believe that error was caused by missing installation

Help please, I'm really don't know what to do.

Comment: Delete all child folders from BUILD folder and try again

Comment: I'm sorry Instab, but where is the build folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @ *Intsab Haider* means that open folder, there;

1. open **C:** folder
2. open **Users** folder
3. open **username** folder
4. open **AndroidStudioProjects** folder
5. open **MyDashboardsAppDjango** folder
6. open **app** folder
7. open **build** folder
   and delete whatever things in folder **build** folder

then go to android-studio and click the run button (a green play arrow) or shift F10
and see if it runs